# Linear Transformations: Which vectors are in R(T)?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm new. I have this mathematical problem from the book: Elementary Linear Algebra. I'm at chapter 8 which is about linear transformations. The question is:

Let $T: R^2\rightarrow R^2$ be the linear operator given by the formula

$T(x,y)=(x-3y,-2x+6y)$

Which of the following vectors are in $R(T)$?

(a) $(1,-2)$

(b) $(3,1)$

(c) $(-2,4)$

Thank you

Comment: If $R(T)$ is supposed to mean the range of $T$, then you are being asked if a solution to the linear system $x - 3y = 1, -2x + 6y = -2$ exists for a), and similarly for b),c).

Comment: Thank you. $R(T)$ is supposed to be a range of T yes. I will try it!

Comment: Hi again. I've solved all three system of eqations. First for a, then b and c.

I can see that a and c gives solutions but b does not. Does this mean that b is the answer? I've tried to insert b's coordinates into $T(x,y)$ and it gives me (0,0).

Answer (score 0):

To ask whether $(a,b) \in R(T)$ is to ask whether $T(x,y) = (a,b)$ has a solution, which is to ask whether the system $x-3y = a, -2x + 6y = b$ has a solution. Note that adding twice the first equation to the second yields $0 = 2a + b$, or $b = -2a$. Thus this system is equivalent to $x - 3y = a$, which has infinitely many solutions, provided that $b = -2a$; if the latter condition is not satisfied, then the system is inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

In the present case, a vector $(a,b)^T$ is in $R(T)$ (which I interpreter as the range of the operator $T$) if there exists $(x,y)^T\in\mathbb{R}^2$ such that:
$$
\left\{\begin{array}{}
 x-3y=a\\
-2x+6y=b\\
\end{array}\right.
$$
You need to substitute the coordinates of the candidate vectors to $a,b$ and try to solve the system that you get. If the system has a solution, then the candidate vector lies in the range; if the system has no solutions, then the vector is not in the range.

Comment: I see but at the first part you write $-3y=a$ why not $x-3y=a$?

Comment: Yeah, that was a typo. ;D